# How to open IE with its maximum window size using VB?

Tags: vb.net

I need to open and also need to able to close a IE window, so I use

```
Proc = Process.Start("C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE", WebLink)
```

and

```
Proc.Kill()
```

However, I also need to make the IE size to be maximum. How I can do that? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the `Process.Start()` overload that accepts a `ProcessStartInfo` as the parameter. Starting your process using this will allow you to set the `ProcessStartInfo.WindowStyle` property to control the window style that the process is to be started with.

If the above doesn't work, you can try to maximize the window by using `ShowWindow()` with the `SW_MAXIMIZE` flag. In order to use native methods from within your managed executable, you will need to use [P/Invoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.showwindow). To get the window handle, you can try using the `Process.MainWindowHandle` property. If this still doesn't work you can try using `EnumWindows()` to iterate through all of the open windows, checking if they're owned by your created process by comparing the process ID (`Process.Id`) to the window's parent process ID (`GetWindowThreadProcessId()`).